# How to set the dynamic url path in static $action?

Tags: apex, visualforce, url

how to set the url path,
Here after deleting the record,i want to redirect the page

```
  <apex:outputLink value="{!URLFOR($Action.Patent__c.Delete, objAsset.id)}">Delete</apex:outputLink>
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? Are you trying to set a redirect?

Comment: yes man @adrian Larsan

Answer (score 1):

You can specify `retURL` as an additional parameter:

```
URLFOR($Action.SomeObject__c.Delete, someId, [retURL='someUrl'])
```

Comment: it is not redirecting - [retURL='apex/TrademarkDetails'] ,after deleting returning back to home page only

Comment: You need to start relative urls with `/`. So it would be `/apex/...`.